CMA-ES - es.tell() Takes Forever to Run and Returns "Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9:SIGKILL)"
I am trying to optimize the weights of an LSTM using the CMA-ES. In my current code, I create the LSTM model, initialize random weights, and create the CMA-ES model.I am using the cma library to create and manage the CMA-ES.
Following this, I ask for solutions from the CMA-ES, and I get a fitness value for each solution. When I have all the possible solutions, I update the "cma.CMAEvolutionStrategy" object using tell.
During this process, the program uses excessive memory, around 80 GB. Moreover, when I come to the es.tell part, the program takes forever to respond and returns the exit code 137 error in the title.
This is a pseudo-code of what I am doing:
model = LSTM(
        input_size=INPUT_SIZE,
        hidden_size=128,
        output_size=OUTPUT_SIZE,
        num_lstm_layers=1,
        num_fc_layers=3,
        fc_hidden_size=64
    )

start_weights = model.get_weights()
es = cma.CMAEvolutionStrategy(start_weights, sigma)
for i in range(100):
       gen_fitness = []
       solutions = es.ask()
       for solution in solutions:
                 gen_fitness.append(get_fitness(solution))
       es.tell(solutions, gen_fitness)

I hope that this is enough information to explain the problem, and I hope that you can help me with it. My program crashes in the first iteration of es.tell(), so this is not a memory piling-up issue.
I tried to run the model with smaller parameters and it was able to work. But the issue is I also have to train my model with a larger LSTM to have more accurate results. I think that having this big of a memory usage makes me think I am doing something completely wrong.
